# Code Regions in JDeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper

Is there a way to define code regions in JDeveloper, like in VS? My purpose is to be able to define collapsible areas of code. I've seen in some places that it supports it, but nowhere does it tell me how to do it.

I didn't figure it'd work, but I tried the #region syntax anyway. It didn't work.

JDeveloper 10.1.3.5

Comment: You may have more luck using syntax used in other Java IDEs, e.g. [NetBeans](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/code_folding/cf_uispec.html) (see "Custom Folds") (no idea if it will work).

Comment: Unfortunately not, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can simply use { ... } around the code if different blocks do not share variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out newer JDeveloper versions like JDeveloper 12c - there is much more control on code folding and what is shown in the editor in that version.

Comment: I do have multiple JDeveloper environments, including a v12 install (but no v12). Unfortunately, the main project I'm working on right now requires v10, as it doesn't convert correctly and crashes v11. I haven't tried v12 (obviously, as I don't have an install), but I would imagine that it would behave similarly.